# Post request to 127.0.0.1:8084/ (Tomcat) takes ~1000ms while to 127.0.0.1/ (Wamp) takes ~20ms

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, post

```
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(address);

    try {
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I am using this code snippet to send a HTTP POST request to a servlet on Apache Tomcat residing on the localhost. The post request (w/o any parameters) to the Tomcat address, i.e., `http://127.0.0.1:8084` takes around 1000 ms. While the same request when sent to Apache (wamp server) at address `http://127.0.0.1` takes only 20ms.

I have already tried it with both Http Versions (1.0/1.1) but the response time has no effect.

Any clue to what may have went wrong? Or how to improve this performance? Or is it the Tomcat itself that is so slow and I can't do anything regarding this issue? (But then browser is able to load the servlets without any significant network delay!)

**Additional Info:**

This code is itself inside a Servlet which is basically doing nothing but just making this request. The servlet that is supposed to handle the request is also 'blank'. Also, there is no JSP involved in the whole scenario. And the timing records are not for cold tomcat. The first and (sometimes) second invocation takes over 2000ms. But consecutive requests get normalized to over 1000ms. SO, it is not a cold tomcat issue for sure.

Now, as people here asked me for the servlet codes as well. Here is the basic design, that I am working on:

Servlet A is supposed to do some work and log it using an AgniLogger class that I wrote. 
That class is in a library and is planned to be used from several components. It in turn is using the above written code for sending the POST request to servlet B. Servlet B will do the actual logging. Now, this servlet B is yet to be implemented. Servlet A and B are part of different web applications.

Servlet A: http://pastebin.com/tQjtvG3g

AgniLogger: http://pastebin.com/nGJypmCN

Servlet B: http://pastebin.com/psCxLCYY

P.S.: I am using Netbeans for development and there is no web.xml in the projects so far.

**Workaround (Very weird though!)**

If I change the definition of processRequest() function in Servlet B from {blank} to this:

```
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        //do nothing
    } finally { 
        out.close();
    }
```

The problem gets solved. The response time is decreased to around 20ms just like Apache (WAMP) server on port 80. But, I have no clue, whatsoever, why is this working fine!

Comment: Please add those "blank" servlets too to the question, just in case they have some relevance. Also, have you tried timing them on the other end, does it take time *after* the servlet has finished processing, or before it? Also, how's your web.xml? Does it have filters or somesuch? Please post that too.

Comment: Updated the question with servlet codes and web.xml info.

Answer (score 2):

you don't give any clue what your servlet does. If it, for example, embeds a jsp in its response, the jsp might need to get compiled into a servlet (the way that jsps are implemented) on first access. Try the second request in this case, which should be a lot faster than the first.

You might also request a page from a "cold" tomcat, e.g. not everything is initialized yet - similar to the first option, this would do some one-time operations that would not appear on later requests.

I've also seen such behaviour in the past when a web- or application server was configured to resolve the client's ip address (into a reverse-lookup DNS address). If this fails, it typically takes a while - and this operation has been blocking the request in the past.

(Clarification for this: I've seen webservers reverse-resolving IP addresses for their log files. This was relatively quick for where it succeeded (but came with a price), but when the requesting IP address could not be resolved, it was logged as just the IP (as you would expect), but with a severe lag that also was visible in the request's answering time. I don't expect any app server to be configured like this out of the box, but I've seen this issue in the past. The drawback is that it might be hard to judge if you're suffering this, if you're only seeing lag - and IP addresses in the log. It's only clear if you see DNS names mixed with IP addresses in the logs for various requesting hosts)

Also, you're giving "127.0.0.1" as an example - in case this is not the real address, make sure that both ways definitely access the same endpoint. E.g. it's common nowadays for "localhost" to resolve to "::1" (the local IPV6 address), but not to "127.0.0.1" (the IPV4 local address). Not that I would expect significant differences from both ways to access the servlet, but if you can identify a different route between the two access options, you might come closer to find the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But there is no JSP involved and neither it is the cold tomcat. Check the additional info I added above.
Can you provide a few more clues about the "when a web- or application server was configured to resolve the client's ip address (into a reverse-lookup DNS address)"? This is something that I have not checked for yet.

Comment: like this? (see additional paragraph)

Comment: For apache tomcat, where should i look for this config? Any clue about that?

Comment: The problem got solved (kinda) but left me with a question that why is it working now?